# Can client-side Blazor code "hear" an event raised server-side?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Can client-side Blazor C# code subscribe to an event raised server-side?

Answer (score 1):

No, you would need SignalR for bi-directional communication between client and server.

Comment: Does that mean, I have to do all the work manually, or is there a predefined way in Blazor to do that, since Blazor seems to be already using SignalR to call a method on the server's class from the client page [as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58212351/455796). For example, what if the "WeatherForcast" has a property and I want to show that value when it is changed by something in the server?

Comment: If you use Server-Side Blazor, everything is rendered server-side anyways and sent to the browser under the hood with SignalR. If you use Client-Side Blazor a.k.a. Blazor WebAssembly there is no SignalR at play. In this case I guess you would have to implement it yourself in the same way you would e.g. in an MVC application. Read about the different hosting models in the Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0